# Illegal string offset 'antrian_seminggu' in controller (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

i am getting error illegal string offset in variable 'antrian_seminggu' in my controller. can you tell me what the probelm. thanks before.

**my controller**

```
public function antrian_seminggu()
{

    $tahun = date('Y');
    $bulan = date('m');
    $tanggal = date('d');
    $format = $tahun.'-'.$bulan.'-'.$tanggal;
    $seminggu = abs(6*86400);
    $awal = strtotime($format);
    $akhir = strtotime($format)+$seminggu;
    for($i=$awal; $i <=$akhir;$i+=86400)
    {

        $data=date('Y-m-d', $i);

        $this->db->select('p.nama as nama_pasien,p.alamat as alamat_pasien, pen.id_pendaftaran as id,pen.tanggal_periksa as tgl, l.nama_layanan as layanan_pasien, pen.nama_detail_layanan as detail_layanan, pen.biaya as biaya_total, d.nama as nama_dokter,pen.status as stat, pen.no_antrian as antrian');
        $this->db->from('pasien p, pendaftaran pen, layanan l, dokter d');
        $this->db->where('p.NIK=pen.NIK');
        $this->db->where('pen.id_layanan=l.id_layanan');
        $this->db->where('l.id_dokter=d.id_dokter');
        $this->db->where('pen.tanggal_periksa',$data);
        $this->db->order_by('pen.tanggal_periksa','ASC');
        $this->db->order_by('d.nama','ASC');
        $this->db->order_by('pen.no_antrian','ASC');
        $query=$this->db->get();
        $data['antrian_seminggu']=$query;

        $this->load->view('admin/antrian_data_seminggu',$data);
    }

}
```

**my view**

```
            <?php
              $no=0;
              foreach ($antrian_seminggu->result() as $dat) 
              {
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`illegal string offset warning` arises when the `array` is not properly set. That could be due to a number of reasons. I'm writing the rectified code below, comments are mentioned wherever necessary. See if it helps you. 
**Controller**

```
public function antrian_seminggu()
{

    $tahun = date('Y');
    $bulan = date('m');
    $tanggal = date('d');
    $format = $tahun.'-'.$bulan.'-'.$tanggal;
    $seminggu = abs(6*86400);
    $awal = strtotime($format);
    $akhir = strtotime($format)+$seminggu;
    for($i=$awal; $i <=$akhir;$i+=86400)
    {

        $date = date('Y-m-d', $i);

        $this->db->select('p.nama as nama_pasien,p.alamat as alamat_pasien, pen.id_pendaftaran as id,pen.tanggal_periksa as tgl, l.nama_layanan as layanan_pasien, pen.nama_detail_layanan as detail_layanan, pen.biaya as biaya_total, d.nama as nama_dokter,pen.status as stat, pen.no_antrian as antrian');
        $this->db->from('pasien p, pendaftaran pen, layanan l, dokter d');
        $this->db->where('p.NIK=pen.NIK');
        $this->db->where('pen.id_layanan=l.id_layanan');
        $this->db->where('l.id_dokter=d.id_dokter');
        $this->db->where('pen.tanggal_periksa',$date);
        $this->db->order_by('pen.tanggal_periksa','ASC');
        $this->db->order_by('d.nama','ASC');
        $this->db->order_by('pen.no_antrian','ASC');
        $query=$this->db->get()->result(); // complete the query here
        $data['antrian_seminggu'][] = $query; // you probably want an array here otherwise the previous value will be overwritten by current value
    }
    $this->load->view('admin/antrian_data_seminggu', $data); // you'd want to load the view only once, so it should be outside the loop.
}
```

**View**

```
<?php
$no=0;
foreach ($antrian_seminggu as $dat) 
{
    var_dump($dat); echo '<br>';   // returns all the data
}
?>
```